# OAuth2RestTemplate for Salesforce is giving error - HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, salesforce, oauth2resttemplate

I am trying to integrate Spring Boot with Salesforce using `OAuth2RestTemplate` but it is giving me `Access token denied` error even though credentials are correct. Upon debugging I found that Salesforce is sending 400 HTTP status code.

```
package com.sentryds.advis.salesforce;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.AuthenticationScheme;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SalesforceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SalesforceApplication.class, args);
        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
        resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
        resourceDetails.setClientId("xxxxxxxx");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("xxxxxxxx");
        resourceDetails.setUsername("xxxxxxxx");
        resourceDetails.setPassword("xxxxxxxx");
        OAuth2RestTemplate auth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);

        try {
            System.out.println(auth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

However if I following this [technique](https://github.com/jamesward/salesforce-rest-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/SalesforceRestStarter.java) then everything works. Only reason I am using `OAuth2RestTemplate` is because it takes care of the token refresh automatically. If there is another way to do so without using OAuthRestTemplate then please let me know that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this problem. I am posting my answer with a hope that it will help someone.

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

resource.setAccessTokenUri("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
resource.setClientId("client_id");
resource.setClientSecret("client_secret");
resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
resource.setUsername("username");
resource.setPassword("password");

OAuth2RestTemplate operations = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultAccessTokenRequest()));
operations.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()); // Not required if you are not doing any conversion
operations.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter()); // Not required if you are not doing any conversion

try {

    System.out.println(auth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken());

} catch (Throwable t) {

    System.out.println(t.getMessage());
}
```